# Grep summary with file name only once

Tags: python, linux, bash, grep, ripgrep

I am trying to figure out a way to summarize the grep results and show results with filename once instead of every line. I know that ripgrep has this feature. I went through grep man page but couldnt find anything similar.

I have a python script that process results of ripgrep. Looking to reuse the same script for grep if i can get the similar results

Any suggestions on how we can implement that.

current grep output

```
\grep  -r "else" .                                                                                                                                             
./historyChecker.py:        else:
./historyChecker.py:    else:
./historyChecker.py:    else:
./historyChecker.py:    else:
```

output that I would like to get

```
historyChecker.py
77:#check if RG is installed else exit
84:        else:
102:    else:
148:    else:
225:    else:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` doesn't have an option to do this, so you'll need to print the filenames yourself in a loop.

```
find . -type f | while read -r filename; do
    if grep -q "else" "$filename"; then 
        echo "$filename"
        grep -n "else" "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately this needs to read each file twice: first to check if there's a match so it will print the filename, then to print all the matches. An alternative would be to write the `grep` output to a temp file, then check if the file is non-empty and print it preceded by `$filename`.

Comment: The response was so quick and efficient. Thanks a lot Barmar, you are awesome!